# weird behavior when writing numbers in the console

Tags: javascript, jquery

`console.log()` for numbers is behaving differently.

Below findings are interesting. Any explanation?

`console.log(1)` - 1

`console.log(01)` - 1

`console.log(12)` - 12

`console.log(012)` - 10

`console.log(0123)` - 83

`console.log(123)` - 123

EDIT

Found this in [MDN documentation:](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Values,_variables,_and_literals)

```
Integers can be expressed in decimal (base 10), hexadecimal (base 16), and octal (base 8).

Decimal integer literal consists of a sequence of digits without a leading 0 (zero).
Leading 0 (zero) on an integer literal indicates it is in octal. Octal integers can include only the digits 0-7.
Leading 0x (or 0X) indicates hexadecimal. Hexadecimal integers can include digits (0-9) and the letters a-f and A-F.
Octal integer literals are deprecated and have been removed from the ECMA-262, Edition 3 standard (in strict mode). JavaScript 1.5 still supports them for backward compatibility.
```

Comment: `console.log(012); // 10` when debugging something weird like this, reduce the code down to eliminate methods that may not be related.

Comment: @KevinB - you're right. Should've done that. Thought that the function is behaving weird. Not to be.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This has nothing to do with jQuery; it's just a feature / quirk of ECMAScript (and therefore JavaScript). Numeric literals beginning with 0 are interpreted in octal, rather than decimal (except in strict mode, in which case it produces a syntax error).

You can verify this by observing `012 === 10` and `0123 === 83`.

Comment: thank you. I calculated it & everything was matching but wasn't sure why octal.

Comment: You can "trim" leading zeroes by using `Number('0123')`

Comment: @NoahHeldman in this case it might be better to use _parseInt_ or _parseFloat_ than _Number_.

Comment: @Paul S.  True, you can use parseInt, but for leading zeroes, you will need the radix component to get the 123 value:  parseInt('0123', 10)

Comment: @NoahHeldman yes, the _radix_ should be given too, however if the browser is standards-compliant you don't actually _need_ it; [**spec**](http://es5.github.io/#x15.1.2.2) (base 8 never gets assumed).